# Text match and search on Mysql table column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, text-search

I have a Mysql table with couple of columns, one column contains `search_text VARCHAR`.
The table is recording data with high frequency and contains millions of records.

I want to search a group of words/texts, which should match from all rows for each or all words. We can pass a date range to restrict a range.

I tried FTS on Mysql, but the response was slow.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `textsearch` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `duration` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timer` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_text` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`search_text`)
)
```

text to search:

> ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "combined words"]

query:

```
SELECT  * FROM textsearch t WHERE MATCH (t.search_text) AGAINST ('word1' IN BOOLEAN MODE)   and t.timer BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2';
```

This will be an array of words/texts. Which need to be searched/matched and for all matches we have to sum the `duration` column from `textsearch` table.

Comment: Can you share that you have tried and some data

Comment: *I tried free text search on Mysql* What is FREE search? maybe you mean fulltext? If so then post your query text. *This will be an array of words/texts* For FTS you must combine this into one search string. *should match from all rows for each or all words* Use boolean search with according modifiers.

Comment: that was full text, got a typo there, edited in original post. The query is also added. I want to search for multiple words, wherever they get a match

Comment: Can you share the query that you have tried ?

Comment: @SelVazi, add the query in original text

Comment: What does `but the response was slow` mean? One person's slow is another person's fast. And vice versa. Please add the EXPLAIN output for your query. Presumably this is a copy n paste error - `FULLTEXT KEY title (title)`? In opening sentence you reference `search_text VARCHAR` but in DDL you have `sentence varchar`

Comment: @nnichols, those were typos and been corrected; reason was the original code can't be shared here. Coming to slow response, question was that it takes an array of words and then grouping to get sum of a column. I wanted to know if there is any other optimal way to do this, or we can tweak itself to get optimal response

Comment: Do you need the some for any row with any of the 3 words?  Or any row with all 3 words?  Or a sum for each word separately?

Comment: @RickJames, I need it with any row having all 3 words

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `HAVING MATCH`  `AGAINST`

`+` stands for AND

`-` stands for NOT

[no operator] implies OR

"some words", is to find rows that contain the exact phrase "some words"

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT *
  FROM textsearch t 
  WHERE t.timer BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-28'
  HAVING MATCH (t.search_text) AGAINST ('+lorem +semper +"Vivamus congue"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
)
select sum(duration)
from cte;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/seW0n2Oe)

[Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: I suspect that this will run quite slowly.  `FULLTEXT` likes to be the _first_ filter; `HAVING` is the last.